# Where did my 7zip archive go?

Tags: 18.04, 7zip

I tried to use 7zip to create an archive for a folder. It compressed all the files and said everything was ok. but I could not find the archive inside the directory containing the folder. Here are my command and part of the output:

```
$p7zip folder/
...
Creating archive: folder/.7z
Items to compress: 786
...
Files read from disk: 653
Archive size: 3155722 bytes (3082 KiB)

Everything is Ok
```

I assumed 7zip created an archive but I could not find it anywhere. Does anyone know where 7zip output the archive?

Comment: It says it created the archive with the filename `folder/.7z`. Try `ls -alF folder/.7z`

Comment: I typed that in and it gave me this line: `-rw-r--r-- 1 ken ken 3155722 Oct 16 15:15 folder/.7z`

Comment: Note that a filename beginning with a single dot is commonly treated as a hidden file, including by "ls" if not adding extra flags. This is likely why you couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 7zip file is in `folder/.7z`. The output of the command tells you: `Creating archive: folder/.7z`. You didn't specify a filename so it made the file without one. Just an extension. I'd recommend using the command `find` if you have problems locating files. Take a look at my example, I've recreated your scenario below.

```
root@myputer:~/test# mkdir folder/  
root@myputer:~/test# p7zip folder/

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21 p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz (306C3),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive: 1 folder, 0 files, 0 bytes

Creating archive: folder/.7z

Items to compress: 1

   Files read from disk: 0  
   Archive size: 90 bytes (1 KiB)   
   Everything is Ok

root@myputer:~/test# find folder
folder folder/.7z

root@myputer:~/test# cd folder/  
root@myputer:~/test/folder# ll 
total 12  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Oct 16 16:34 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 me      me      4096 Oct 16 16:33 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root      90 Oct 16 16:34 .7z
```

There is your file `.7z`.

Comment: Ah I see. So it's still inside the directory but without a filename. No wonder I used `ls` and it didn't list the archive.

Comment: Yes, because you made the file with a dot, when you did a ls it returned nothing. You have to do a `ls -a` or `ll` which will show you all files. See the man page for the -a (all) parameter. It will make sense.

Comment: @G_Style selecting multiline terminal output in your answer and clicking the `{}` button in the editor will format it properly with proper linebreaks and everything.